# Facebook Login takes me to Help Page

Tags: authentication, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

I have had the facebook connect set up for over a few months and have done a lot of testing on it and everything seems to be working correctly. Suddenly when I try to login using the php facebook sdk I get redirected to the following page https://www.facebook.com/help/258359927634494

It seems to let me login on occasion, but it usually redirects to this page. I assume my app was reported however we only have a few test users at this time as we are in beta and I stopped my app from asking for repeatedly for post permissions a while back as soon as I was aware it was doing that. What can I do to clear up the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message appears when an app loads the login dialog many times in a short duration.  Make sure you are only loading the dialog once per user.  Until this redirect behavior is tweaked to be me more lenient, try waiting ~30 seconds between tests.